# Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...THtwvnO2F9FWD7HrMJoGZ'

Tags: node.js, json

i am trying to create a nuxt project using npx create-nuxt-app and am having this error `Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...THtwvnO2F9FWD7HrMJoGZ'` haw can i solve it.

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...THtwvnO2F9FWD7HrMJoGZ'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/ferdinand/.npm/_logs/2019-09-06T11_50_45_307Z-debug.log
>
> /home/ferdinand/.npm/_npx/11891/lib/node_modules/create-nuxt-app/node_modules/sao/lib/installPackages.js:108
>           throw new SAOError(`Failed to install ${packageName} in ${cwd}`)
>           ^
>
> SAOError: Failed to install packages in
>   /home/ferdinand/Documents/projects/testApp
>       at ChildProcess. (/home/ferdinand/.npm/_npx/11891/lib/node_modules/create-nuxt-app/node_modules/sao/lib/installPackages.js:108:15)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {   __sao: true }

Comment: It's an error about a problem in JSON-encoded string. Please paste it, so I can help you

Answer (score 3):

Might be a cache issue, try installing without using your NPM cache:

```
npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache
```

If so, clean your NPM cache by running:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to solve this issue more than 1 day. It is a cache issue.
Using the following statement not to solve my issue

```
npm cache clean --force
```

I have to delete folder npm-cache and the issue is solved. The folder is in %AppData%/Roaming/npm-cache. My OS is Windows 10.